# remove cache in webrrot files directory

Tags: cakephp-1.2

How to disable cache for files folder in webroot for cake 1.2 version

Problem:
i have pdf files uploaded to webroot/files/products/example.pdf

if i access http://example.com/cakeproject/files/products/example.pdf , pdf is displayed

and when i update example.pdf with new pdf and access http://example.com/cakeproject/files/products/example.pdf , the old pdf is displayed.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear this folder :

**yourwebsite\app\tmp\cache**

Comment: i have clear it everytime and restart the server then it works fine. but from the cakephp function how can we disable the cache to the files folder (webroot\files\)